# How to draw two color arc in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to draw circle, which will be colored with two colors. One color from 0 to 180 degree, and second color for the rest. I have something like this:

```
private void drawCircle(Canvas c)
{
    RectF oval = new RectF(20, 20, 100, 100);

    c.drawArc(oval, 0, 180, false, getPaintWithColor(R.color.background));
    c.drawArc(oval, 180, 360, false, getPaintWithColor(R.color.font_grey));
}

private Paint getPaintWithColor(int colorId){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(colorId));

    return paint;
}
```

But after this, arc is monocolored with `font_grey` color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Canvas documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

> *sweepAngle*   Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise
>
> If the sweep angle is >= 360, then the oval is drawn completely.

The `sweepAngle` parameter isn't the ending angle, it's the size of the angle in degrees. Your second arc is drawing a complete oval, since your angle is `360`.

Try using `180` for the sweep angle.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now, maybe you can tell me why this circle is so sharp, I have `setAntiAlias` call and even `setDither` and still this circle is just ugly:/

Comment: Not sure I can really help with that. It might be worth it to ask as a separate question if you can't get it looking good. I'd include screenshots of the "ugly" one, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  Shader gradient = new SweepGradient (0,getMeasuredHeight()/2, Color.RED, Color.WHITE);
  lighted.setShader(gradient);
  canvas.drawArc(rectf, -90, 360, false, lightRed);
```